# How to return to previous activity when the code is executed

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm getting an error in this code.

```
Intent voltar = new Intent(this,A.class);
voltar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
context.startActivity(voltar);
```

The error concerning the "A" that is "(this, a.class)"

I want the app, return to activity when running the code, it back up, but after that when you open the app it notifies you of an error and asks to send to google, always.

I got the code on the internet, so I think this part (this, a.class)

It is the sole example cited and does not apply to my project, already tried to remove, but meso so error persists. 
Can anyone help me?

I can suppress the error message, or fix?

Comment: Already tried to call `finish()` in the second `Activity`, to back to the first `Activity`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Say you have activity `C`, `B` and `A`. `C` starts `B`, `B` starts `A`, and when you are done with `A`, you want to skip `B` and return to `C` directly. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Intent voltar = new Intent(this,A.class);
```

into:

```
Intent voltar = new Intent(context, A.class);
```